# integration between Azure Communication Service with MS BOT Framework

Tags: azure-communication-services

I want to connect Azure Communication Service with Bot service. Is it possible to connect Azure Communication Service with MS BOT Framework to manage Voice (IVR) and chat flows?

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to connect Azure Communication Services with the MS Bot Framework to manage IVR and chat.

The product group did mention that you can share your vision or business requirement with them to help them better understand how this functionality could better assist you. To do this, please create an issue on their [GitHub repro](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/issues) so they receive your feedback.